# MySQL: Select rows by the reverse criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

The first query I wrote is:

```
select t.groupNum from table1 t
JOIN table1 s
on t.groupNum=s.groupNum
and t.id!=s.id 
and t.bool='true' and s.bool='true';
```

This query selects such groups that contain at least two 'true' within the group. Right?

I need to select all groups that have **exactly zero** 'true' values (only t.bool='false' which is the second possible value among two values 'true' and 'false').

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having` to do this.

```
select groupNum
from table1
group by groupNum
having sum(bool='true') = 0
```

MySQL treats conditions as booleans returning `1` when the condition is True and `0` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT t.groupNum
FROM table1 t
GROUP BY t.groupNum
HAVING COUNT(t.bool = 'true') = 0;
```

I'm not sure why you're doing the self join. Also is the t.bool column actually a text value with the values of 'true' and 'false'?

Comment: Also is the t.bool column actually a text value with the values of 'true' and 'false'?  - Thanks for the question. No, it is not. It's just for example to make it more clear from the first view.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the response. I notice my answer is similar to @vkp answer - hope we're on the right track!

Comment: a simple copy-paste of my answer :)

Comment: It seems that way - I saw your answer appear after I submitted mine and saw that they were very similar. I guess we had the same thoughts when coming up with the answer :)

Comment: not a problem..but your original answer was totally different.